# 'Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable' facing this error when running testcafe testcases in saucelabs

Tags: azure, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, saucelabs

What im trying to do here:
Im trying to run testcafe scripts through azure pipelines in SauceLabs.
Trying to run through **localhost** URL, as we are yet to figure out the authentication strategies.
The testcases are passing when i see the video in SauceLabs build job, but end of the run testcase is failing with this error.

1. Unhandled promise rejection:

   Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable
   at ServerResponse.pipe (_http_outgoing.js:821:22)
   at Object.respondOnWebSocket

(/Users/runner/work/1/s/apps/atom-testcafe/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/websocket.js:32:13)
at Array.decideOnProcessingStrategy

(/Users/runner/work/1/s/apps/atom-testcafe/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/stages.js:75:25)
at Object.run

(/Users/runner/work/1/s/apps/atom-testcafe/node_modules/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/index.js:19:34)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

```
  Browser: Chrome 90.0.4430.85 / Windows 10
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Would you mind submitting a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and adding as much information as possible to the template?

Answer (score 0):

From [the submitted bug](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4963), it looks like the problem might have been that your corporate proxy was preventing connections to Sauce Labs' OnDemand endpoint.

Tunnels, the REST API, Real Devices and Browsers/Virtual Devices can all have different endpoints to connect too.  If your networking team only makes exceptions for specific ports and/or URLs, they might not have allowed enough access.